# How to start Jupyter notebook on another drive in Mac OS Anaconda Navigator?

Tags: anaconda

I like the idea of using Anaconda Navigator to manage environments. On my Mac, the Anaconda Navigator is installed on the main drive. I would like to put working notebooks on another hard drive. However, Jupyter notebook cannot navigate to another hard drive.

How do I configure the system so that I can work on the files on another hard drive and keep the Anaconda on the main drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I think the best way is to use Anaconda Navigator to configure packages, but start the Jupyter notebook in terminal. One can navigate to the desired drive first by the commands:

```
ls /Volumes
cd /Volumes/MyNewDrive
```

The start the notebook by:

```
Jupyter notebook
```

Comment: And if you want to start JupyterLab, follow as above and use:
 ```Jupyter lab```