# How Do I change Anaconda so Jupyter runs in another drive

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have two drives on my Mac

an SSD with my apps
a larger HDD for my docs

Anaconda and jupyter are on the SDD . My docs are on the HDD

I want to run jupyter so my files on are on the HDD.

## WHAT I HAVE TRIED

THis solution is available here [How to start Jupyter notebook on another drive in Mac OS Anaconda Navigator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51802061/how-to-start-jupyter-notebook-on-another-drive-in-mac-os-anaconda-navigator) but does do what I want.

I can load jupyter via the terminal if I

1. Navigate to the drive and directory I want

```
jupyter notebook
```

This is not a good solution though as other people need to use my workbook. I feel should be able to change the settings in anaconda to look at the drive and load jupyter, this would be easier than having to navigate through my drive and load it in terminal. It is also much easier for other people in my team.

Are there setting files somewhere or can I even change the working drive in anaconda (I cannot see this option in preferences)

Answer (score 0):

use this command: **cd /d d:** on anaconda prompt if your drive is **D** drive